# how to measure power of a sound wave produced by a whistle?

Tags: power, sound

i have a galtons whistle producing frequency of 10khz.
I have no idea how to measure the power aassociated with it.
Also if i say (10khz,10w) what does it mean?
is it even possible to link mechanical sound waves with energy?
other gadgets have voltage and current which will give the power but how can we estimate power with a whistle?
we blow the whistle using an air compressor.

Answer (score 3):

[Acoustic impedance](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/SoundSoundSound.htm) is the key factor in all of this.

It is approximately 410 pascal-seconds per metre ( or N-s/m\$^3\$)at 25 deg C.

So if you have an SPL of 94 dB (1 pascal), there is a a power associated with it of 1\$^2\$/410 = 0.0024 watts per square metre. This is quite a handy diagram: -

[image]

Taken from [here](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/FormulaWheel-Acoustics.htm)

It's just like electrical power = V\$^2\$/R

> I have no idea how to measure the power associated with it.

So, measure the SPL and estimate the total surface area that this SPL is being projected onto from the point source. If you estimate 100 sq metres then total power emanating from the source is 0.24 watts.

It doesn't matter how far from the source you are - the SPL will reduce but the surface area will increase and you will still be able to calculate the power at the equivalent point source.

It's also very similar to EM waves. If the electric field (E) is 1 volt/metre, the power (watts per metre) is E\$^2\$/Z where Z is the impedance of free space (approximately 377 ohms). So 1V/m implies an RF power of 0.0026 watts per square metre.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, sound intensity is measured with **sound pressure level** (SPL). SPL is measured in dB (and must be associated with a distance from the source to be meaningful).

dB SPL is measured relative to \$p_0 = 20\mu \text{Pa}\$, 1 Pa = 94 dB. If you are completely unfamiliar with dB SPL, 20 dB is quiet, 100 dB is loud, 140 dB is the threshold of pain.

SPL meters are easy to obtain and not particularly expensive. Of course, a highly accurate and well-calibrated SPL meter will be more expensive/difficult to obtain.

It is not meaningful to compare power into a source when you are measuring output acoustic energy unless you know driver efficiencies of both sources: for instance, 1W into two different speakers may result in wildly different SPLs if the speakers have a large difference in efficiency. Acoustic driver efficiency is typically measured in dB/W @ 1m. If a driver outputs 102 dB @ 1W, 1m it is 20% efficient. However, an inefficient driver might output 86dB @ 1W, 1m, which is more like 0.2% efficiency.

So, yes, it is possible to correlate "mechanical sound waves" (SPL) with energy. If measured correctly, SPL will tell you how much acoustic power is being radiated by the driver, but that alone will not tell you how much electrical power is being dissipated in the load. You must either measure, or know the efficiency.